# User has Graduated from 3 Universities Nodejs restApi Sequelize

Tags: express, rest, sequelize.js, nodes

I am tring to create a rest api with nodejs express and sequelize
but how can i give a user two or more univerities that graduated and year of graduated

is there anyway that i can give datatype object so i can give university an year
or if i have to make relations between them could you give me a relation design

can you give me an idea please?